# The expected-value of the square of Sample Variance.

Tags: probability, expected-value

Suppose $X_1, \cdots, X_n$ are i.d.d. samples from population $X \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, and the sample variance is denoted by
$T = \sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{(X_i - \overline{X})^2}{n}$.
I am curious about the expected-value of $T^2$, which is the square of $T$.
Apparently the key problem is what the distribution of $T^2$ is ?
According to my intuition, it may be some kind of F-distribution, but how to prove it ,especially to solve the cross term is the biggest problem that I have encountered.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Distribution_of_the_sample_variance Both normal case, and the general case are given, for the variance of the sample variance. Then you add back $\sigma^4$ to obtain the desired moment. Usually we denote $S^2$ to be the sample variance and $S$ for the sample standard deviation.

Comment: What I want is the "square" of the sample variance.

Answer (score 1):

Working from a random sample $\mathbf X=\{X_1,\dots,X_n\}$ with mutually independent $X_i\sim\mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, the distribution of the *unbiased* sample variance
$$
S^2=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\bar X)^2
$$
is distributed according to the gamma distribution (shape-rate parameterization)
$$
S^2\sim\operatorname{Gamma}\left(\frac{n-1}{2},\frac{n-1}{2\sigma^2}\right).
$$
Since we are using the rate parameterization of the gamma distribution and $T=\frac{n-1}{n}S^2$ is follows that
$$
T\sim\operatorname{Gamma}\left(\underbrace{\frac{n-1}{2}}_{\alpha},\underbrace{\frac{n}{2\sigma^2}}_{\beta}\right).
$$
To find $\mathsf E(T^2)$ we then write
$$
\mathsf E(T^2)=\int_0^\infty t^2f_T(t)\,\mathrm dt=\frac{\beta^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\int_0^\infty t^{\alpha+2-1}e^{-\beta t}\,\mathrm dt.
$$
Substituting $u=\beta t$ then gives
$$
\mathsf E(T^2)=\frac{\beta^\alpha}{\beta^{\alpha+2}\Gamma(\alpha)}\int_0^\infty u^{\alpha+2-1}e^{-u}\,\mathrm du=\frac{\Gamma(\alpha+2)}{\beta^2\Gamma(\alpha)}.
$$
Using the property $x\Gamma(x)=\Gamma(x+1)$ this result simplfies to
$$
\mathsf E(T^2)=\frac{(\alpha+1)\alpha}{\beta^2}=\frac{(n+1)(n-1)}{n^2}\sigma^4=\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\sigma^4.
$$
Note for large $n$ this becomes
$$
\mathsf E(T^2)\sim\sigma^4+\mathcal O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right).
$$

Answer (score 0):

You might now this forumla:
$$
\text{Var}[X] = E[X^2] - E[X]^2
$$
I.e.
$$
E[X^2] = \text{Var}[X] + E[X]^2
$$
The variance is the expected value of the squared variable, but centered at its expected value.

In this case, the random variable is the sample distribution, which has a Chi-squared distribution – see the link in the comment.